# C# Вывод результата выполнения консоли в файл

Tags: c#, cmd

Подскажите как вывести в текстовый файл всё, что пишет в консоли запущенная мной сторонние консольное приложение. Запускаю приложение следующим образом:

```
Process Process = new Process();
Process.StartInfo.FileName = pathPOST;
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = pathTemp+" "+command;
Process.Start();
```

Где первый аргумент - путь до .exe а второй просто код, который требует сторонние ПО. Приложение запускается - пишет данные о выполнение(предупреждения, ошибки и тд), а потом просит нажатия интера для закрытия.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](http://www.csharpcoderr.com/2012/09/console-to-winform.html)

Comment: А если попробовать что-то на подобии этого: [How to save Console.WriteLine output to text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4470751/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
    Process Process = new Process();
    Process.StartInfo.FileName = pathPOST;
    Process.StartInfo.Arguments = pathTemp+" "+command;
    Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
    Process.Start();

if (!Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
  return;

string line;
StreamReader sr1 = Process.StandardOutput;

hile (!sr1.EndOfStream) {
  line = sr1.ReadLine();
  File.AppendAllText("D:\\log.txt", line+"\r\n");
}
```

Вдруг кому-то поможет. Единственное, теперь сторонние приложение выдаёт ошибку. Не может найти какую-то библиотеку.